# Android application is not compatible with my device

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I've created application on android, the main goal was: User is logging with his Google Account, scans an NFC Tag, sends the information of user login and tag to server using volley library and getting response. 
Everything was working fine when, I was using Android studio and usb debugging, everything wrks fine. I've put the app on to google play store and it's not compatible with my p9 lite, or any other phone with NFC. So I can't even download app.
 This is screenshot from Google Play:[image]

And here is my Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="some.package.name">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.nfc"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is also my gradle build Project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And gradle build app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'key0'
            storeFile file('C:/AndroidKey/RandomKey.jks')
            keyPassword 'randomKey'
            storePassword 'randomPassword'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "someId"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.02"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.0.5'
    compile 'hanks.xyz:htextview-library:0.1.5'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Everything works fine connected by USB but I can't even download application from Google Play Store. 
What can I do in that case? Thanks and greetings.

EDIT:
I've change the 
`<uses-feature android:name="android.nfc"/>` to 
`<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc"/>`
 but still the same situation: 
 [image]

EDIT: My device has NFC, and when I click at the options to show the compatible devices for my app it's there.[image]

Comment: Because your devices don't have nfc. `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found a solution, thanks everyone for hints, the answer is not in the manifest, so sorry for confusing question.
 [Private apps in company](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2494992?hl=en)

I'm not the administrator of google play developer console, and the owner didn't check the rights to

> Allow users to update Google Play Private Channel

so when developing a company apps this option is necessary.
Thanks for help and greetings.

EDIT: Also the device must have a work profile to install the app, it's working now.

Comment: This right Allow users to update Google Play Private Channel is required for all issues ?? as i m getting same error your app is not compatible with this device

Answer (score 2):

The correct tag is

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc"/>
```

If your app also works on devices that don't have an NFC chip, you should add `android:required="false"` to the above tag.

Answer (score 2):

If your app works with devices without nfc module, you should change your `uses-feature` like that:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />
```

If your app doesn't work with devices without nfc module, you should have compatible device with nfc and change your `uses-feature` like that:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to update `<uses-feature>` tag as

```
<uses-feature 
   android:name="android.hardware.nfc"  
   android:required="false" />
```

That's it! You will go live!